# Android Tests: Stubbing out Retrofit with Mockito

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mockito, retrofit

In my `MainActivity` I have a method called `getAPI` that returns an `OTBServiceWrapper`. This is used to setup retrofit for calling to an API.

In my `MainActivityTest` file I am trying to stub out the `new OTBService().getService()` call that the `getApi` method is making so I can return a `MockedOTBService` which changes the client to a custom one that return `json`.

As is, the current implementation will it the `MockedOTBService` if I had to place a logger within `MockedOTBService` but also falls through and calls the real api, which is not want I want in a test.

I am trying to stub the Retrofit API calls using Mockito and return `json`. I cant seem to understand why the stub is being called yet is not stubbing the method in question.

**Notes:**

1. I am using `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`
2. I am only running one test
3. If I add a `verify(mockedOTBService, atLeastOnce()).getService();` is says it was never called.
4. If I change the `when...thenReturn` to use a `mMainActivity = spy(getActivity())` there is not change and the real API is called.

**Logcat Output**

```
Logger﹕ MockedOTBService was called // Mock is called
Logger﹕ Real OTBService was called // Real API is called
Logger﹕ MainActivity getAPI method class is "$Proxy1" // Mock is shown in MainActivity
Logger﹕ RealAPIResponse JSON Parsed ID: 266 // Real API response returned
```

**Real Flow**

MainActivity.onCreate() > OTBService.getService() > OTBServiceWrapper.createSearch(...)

**Trying to Achieve within Tests**

MainActivity.onCreate() > MockedOTBService.getService() > OTBServiceWrapper.createSearch(...)

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private OTBServiceWrapper serviceWrapper;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getApi().createSearch(...)
  }

  public OTBServiceWrapper getApi() {
    return new OTBService().getService();
  }
}
```

OTBService.java

```
public class OTBService {
  public OTBServiceWrapper getService() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(Constants.API_URL)
        .build();

    return restAdapter.create(OTBServiceWrapper.class);
  }
}
```

OTBServiceWrapper.java

```
public interface OTBServiceWrapper {
  @POST(Constants.API_SEARCHES_POST_URL)
  void createSearch(@Body Request request, Callback<Request.Response> callback);
}
```

MainActivityTest.java

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
  private OTBService mMockedOTBService;
  private MainActivity mMainActivity;
  private View mSearchButton;

  public MainActivityTest() { super(MainActivity.class); }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);

    System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath());

    mMockedOTBService = mock(OTBService.class);
    when(mMockedOTBService.getService()).thenReturn(new MockedOTBService(getInstrumentation().getContext()).getService());

    mMainActivity = getActivity();

    mSearchButton = mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.AbSearchButton);
    mYourHolidayButton = mMainActivity.findViewById(R.id.AbYourHolidayButton);
  }

  public void testButtonActions() {
    TouchUtils.clickView(this, mSearchButton);
    ...
  }
}
```

MockedOTBService.java

```
public class MockedOTBService {
  private Context context;

  public MockedOTBService(Context context) { this.context = context; }

  public OTBServiceWrapper getService() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter;

    restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setClient(new LocalJsonClient(context))
        .setEndpoint(Constants.API_TEST_URL)
        .build();

    return restAdapter.create(OTBServiceWrapper.class);
  }
}
```

LocalJsonClient.java

```
@SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
public class LocalJsonClient implements Client { ... }
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the need for mocking your request by allowing the Activity to set the service.

In your `MainActivity` create a class variable and a class setter for the service. It needs to be a at the class scope to prevent the `OnCreate` method being called before you have set the service to what you want it to be. Also create an instance getter which sets the service if you have not already.

In your test before you call `getActivity()` set the service to be your mock service. (Maybe think about moving this out to a support object).

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static OTBServiceWrapper serviceWrapper;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getServiceWrapper.createSearch(...)
  }

  public OTBServiceWrapper getServiceWrapper() {
    if (serviceWrapper == null) {
      MainActivity.setServiceWrapper(new OTBService().getService());
    }

    return serviceWrapper;
  }

  public static void setServiceWrapper(OTBServiceWrapper serviceWrapper) {
    MainActivity.serviceWrapper = serviceWrapper;
  }
}
```

MainActivityTest.java

```
public class MainActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
  private MainActivity mMainActivity;

  public MainActivityTest() { super(MainActivity.class); }

  @Override
  protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    setActivityInitialTouchMode(true);

    MainActivity.setServiceWrapper(
      new MockedOTBService(getInstrumentation().getContext()).getService()
    );

    mMainActivity = getActivity();
  }
}
```